# Como numerar o alfabeto e somar suas letras obtendo um resultado a cada palavra escrita?

Tags: java

Queria obter o resultado de palavras com suas letras somadas...

Exemplo:  `a=1 b=2 c=3` se eu digitar a palavra `"bac"` o resultado seria `"6".`

Porque somou as 3 letras `a+b+c=6`.

Tentei esse código mas não funciona:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

Scanner on = new Scanner(System.in); 
System.out.println("Digite a palavra: ");

String soma;

soma = on.nextLine();

char a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z;

a=1; b=2; c=3; d=4; e=5; f=6; g=7; h=8; i=9; j=10; k=11; l=12; m=13; 
n=14; o=15; p=16; q=17; r=18; s=19; t=20; u=21; v=22; w=23; x=24; y=25; z=26;   

System.out.println(soma);    

  }  
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O que o seu código está fazendo é simplesmente imprimir o que alguém digita. Você precisa adicionar a lógica de somatório e mapeamento do alfabeto. Para isso, você pode realizar as seguintes modificações:

1- Criar um método que contabiliza as somas:

```
private static int calcularSomaPalavra(String palavra, Map<Character, Integer> alfabeto) {
    int valorSoma = 0;
    for (char caractere : palavra.toCharArray()) {
        if (isCaractereEncontrado(alfabeto, caractere))
            valorSoma += getValorCaractere(alfabeto, caractere);
    }
    return valorSoma;
}
```

O que foi feito foi criar um método que dado uma palavra obtém a soma dos caracteres da palavra, simples assim. A grande sacada aqui é verificar se o caractere possui um valor numérico mapeado e somá-lo ao totalizador. Isso pode ser feito de várias formas, por simplicidade você pode utilizar um `Map`:

```
// Declaração do map de letras do alfabeto.
Map<Character, Integer> alfabeto = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

//Mapeamento dos valores de cada letra do alfabeto
alfabeto.put('a', 1);
alfabeto.put('b', 2);
...
alfabeto.put('z', 26);

private static Integer getValorCaractere(Map<Character, Integer> alfabeto, char caractere) {
    return alfabeto.get(caractere);
}

private static boolean isCaractereEncontrado(Map<Character, Integer> alfabeto, char caractere) {
    return getValorCaractere(alfabeto, caractere) != null;
}
```

Com a utilização de um `Map`, a lógica de verificação do valor numérico do caracter trata-se apenas da chamada do método `get`.

2- Imprimir a soma da palavra:

```
int valorSoma = calcularSomaPalavra(soma, alfabeto);
System.out.println(valorSoma);
```

Agora você está imprimindo de fato a soma, e não apenas o que o usuário digita. Juntando tudo, teríamos:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Character, Integer> alfabeto = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    Scanner on = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Digite a palavra: ");

    String soma;

    soma = on.nextLine();

    alfabeto.put('a', 1);
    alfabeto.put('b', 2);
    ...
    alfabeto.put('z', 26);

    int valorSoma = calcularSomaPalavra(soma, alfabeto);
    System.out.println(valorSoma);

}

private static int calcularSomaPalavra(String palavra, Map<Character, Integer> alfabeto) {
    int valorSoma = 0;
    for (char caractere : palavra.toCharArray()) {
        if (isCaractereEncontrado(alfabeto, caractere))
            valorSoma += getValorCaractere(alfabeto, caractere);
    }
    return valorSoma;
}

private static Integer getValorCaractere(Map<Character, Integer> alfabeto, char caractere) {
    return alfabeto.get(caractere);
}

private static boolean isCaractereEncontrado(Map<Character, Integer> alfabeto, char caractere) {
    return getValorCaractere(alfabeto, caractere) != null;
}
```

Uma dica é sempre pegar um problema e dividí-lo em etapas de resolução, assim você consegue resolver um problema maior resolvendo cada etapa dele, o que facilita a elaboração da solução global.

Comment: Olá @Giuliana Bezerra Muito Obrigado!!!! Muito boa sua explicação!!!! Realmente muito show!!! Você é Demais!!!!

Answer (score 10):

É bem simples usando a matemática:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Ideone {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner on = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Digite a palavra: ");
        String texto = on.nextLine();
        int soma = 0;
        for (char caractere : texto.toCharArray()) { //varre cada caractere
            //"A" vale 97, então tira 96 e assim por diante
            soma += caractere > 96 && caractere < 123 ? caractere - 96 : 0;
        }
        System.out.println(soma);    
    }  
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/551JRW). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ncbwwdtd-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/Cypher.java).

Outras coisas podem ser feitas diferentemente, mas a pergunta não dá requisitos claros.

O importante é que essa solução usa o princípio de [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). Nunca complique o que pode ser simples. Há problemas que são inerentemente complexos e só podemos gerenciá-los bem. Soluções complicadas podem e devem ser evitadas.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta!!! @bigown